# Docker Image build failure with Spotify plugin trying to connect to localhost:2375 [Spring/Maven]

Tags: spring, docker, maven, dockerfile, microservices

Command issued[in the root project directory where Dockerfile is located]:

**mvn dockerfile:build**

Output[partial]:

```
.
.
.
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:481)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run (ApacheConnector.java:491)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute (MoreExecutors.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:50)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:37)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:487)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run (ClientRuntime.java:178)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:271)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:267)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:315)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:297)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:267)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope (RequestScope.java:340)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$3.run (ClientRuntime.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute (MainClientExec.java:380)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:236)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute (RetryExec.java:88)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute (RedirectExec.java:110)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:435)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run (ApacheConnector.java:491)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute (MoreExecutors.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:50)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:37)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:487)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run (ClientRuntime.java:178)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:271)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:267)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:315)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:297)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:267)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope (RequestScope.java:340)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$3.run (ClientRuntime.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect (Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow (Net.java:672)
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect (NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect (NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:633)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket (PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute (MainClientExec.java:380)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:236)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute (RetryExec.java:88)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute (RedirectExec.java:110)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:435)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run (ApacheConnector.java:491)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute (MoreExecutors.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:50)
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit (AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:37)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply (ApacheConnector.java:487)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run (ClientRuntime.java:178)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:271)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call (Errors.java:267)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:315)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:297)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process (Errors.java:267)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope (RequestScope.java:340)
    at com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$3.run (ClientRuntime.java:210)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:539)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:833)
[INFO] dockerfile: null
[INFO] 
[INFO] Image will be built as ostock/licensing-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.695 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-07T12:57:23+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.13:build (default-cli) on project licensing-service: Could not build image: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionExcepti
on: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: no further information -> [Help 1]
```

Plugin config in pom.xml:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>push</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Version-related info:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35-desktop+001
 Version:           24.0.5
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.6
 Git commit:        ced0996
 Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:36:24 2023
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Desktop 4.22.1 (118664)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.5
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.6
  Git commit:       a61e2b4
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

*Note*: The **Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS** option is turned off and I don't feel comfortable turning it on, given the warning associated. Hopefully there are alternatives to make this work ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is about failure to connect via *http* to localhost:2375.